# Wifi is connected, but after a while ping to access point doesn't work. (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

I have an Asus G55V laptop on which I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and which I upgraded to 12.04 LTS last summer. I have the laptop for almost 2 years and so far I had no wireless connection issues with. However yesterday evening something strange started to happen while using it on my home wireless network.

After a while browsing, sites started not to load anymore so I checked to see the router connection and if my other devices worked. All seemed fine and then I tried disconnecting and reconnecting to the network a few times to no avail. When I pinged my router, I would get no response.

The problem seems to be disappearing if I restart the laptop or router (not the other devices work without the need of restarting the router), but it seems to repeat after a while.

Have any of you encountered similar issues and if so, is there a way to solve this without the need of restarting either device?

Thanks,
Mihai